# RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (320) must match the existing size (224) at non-singleton dimension 2

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to train a model on UCF11 dataset in PyTorch.

I am trying to implement a random augmentation on the video data samples.

```
self.transforms_list = [transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.225),
                            transforms.ColorJitter(contrast=0.225),
                            transforms.ColorJitter(saturation=0.1),
                            transforms.ColorJitter(hue=0.1),
                            transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
                            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.25),
                            transforms.RandomRotation(30.0),
                            transforms.GaussianBlur((5,5), sigma=(0.1, 2.0))]

transformations = random.sample(self.transforms_list,random.randint(1,8))+[transforms.RandomCrop(224)]
transformations = transforms.Compose(transformations)
```

But when I try to apply these transformations on each frame of a video clip, I get this error

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (320) must match the existing size (224) at non-singleton dimension 2.  
Target sizes: [3, 240, 320].  Tensor sizes: [3, 224, 224]
```

Cannot understand why this error is occurring. I checked the source code but I cannot see the reason this error should occur.

I created a custom transform class for the RandomCrop but still the same error occurs.

Please help!!

**EDIT**:

Since, the input is a video, the input has shape (T,C,H,W)

I was applying the transformations on each frame in the video like this

`vid[i]  = transformations(vid[i])`

Created a new variable `new_vid = []` and changed the code to

`new_vid.append(transformations(vid[i]))`

In the end,
`vid = torch.cat(new_vid,dim = 0)`

I got a video with shape (T,3,224,224)

Comment: Where did the error occur? at `torch.cat`? after the `RandomCrop` all frame should be size (3,224,224), it may happen because you try to concatenate frame with different shape

Comment: @Mr. For Example .... I used `torch.cat` to create a separate tensor. Before that I was trying to assign the cropped frame to `vid[i]` and that was causing the error because it had a different shape by mistake. The **EDIT** part is actually how the error got solved.